# Is webpack a necessary (or at least commonly used) technology for an enterprise level Angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, bundle, frontend

The point of bundle.js is to get rid of complications out of specific chains of dependencies, but the use of components seem to localize needs of individual pages (as well as CSS is concerned): perhaps I'm missing the big picture of one of the two?

Comment: Not that good type of question... Can be used? Yes. Required? No. Good? Depends...

Comment: Well, Angular promotes the use an angular-cli to develop and build Angular apps. And angular-cli is based on webpack. So yes, I'd say it's very commonly used. The point of Angular is to make a single page app. so you create a bundle (or several ones, if using lazy-loading), containing all your coponents, services, pipes, directives, styles, etc.